# Why is the image affecting my <nav> size?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I want the navigation bar to have the same size regardless of screen size.
I was able to do it with the following CSS.
However, when I add an image below it, its size is no longer fixed and change with the screen size.
I tried to analyze this behavior but I couldn't understand why it behaves that way.
Can someone explain it to me?

Thank you

```css
.navigation-bar {
  background-color: rgba(232, 229, 228, 0.5);
  height: 60px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="testforanything.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navigation-bar">
      <a href="home.html">Home</a>
      <a href="profile.html">Profile</a>
      <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </nav>

    <!-- When I remove the image, the problem disappears. -->
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1024x724/000/ffffff.jpg" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine to me. Or perhaps I don't understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your image not responsive and your screen size can not be reduces after reach your image size. Make your image responsive you will be good to go. I make it some thing like that but you can do however you want depending what you want with your image.
`

```
.navigation-bar {
  background-color: rgba(232, 229, 228, 0.5);
  height: 60px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

/*added part */

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

`